# Mail alert from MySQL when databases are edited

Tags: mysql

How do I get mail from MySQL when root or someone else edits or updates a particular database? It should trigger sending a mail and log the edits.

I have tried Triggers but its not working.

Server specifications:

- Ubuntu 10.04 64 Bit
- MySQL Server 5.1.41

script which i have tried

```
  #!/bin/sh

  tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log | egrep 'INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|root'
      | mail -s 'backend update' sushanth@example.com
```

but its not working

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has no particular SMTP setup, mechanisms, or drivers whatsoever built in.

However, there are two basic things you can do the kind of monitoring you want.

**Option 1 : You Could Monitor the Binary Logs**

If binary logs are enabled, you could write a shell script to call mysql and do SHOW MASTER STATUS; If either the filename or filesize changes, something changed. Once detected, you could send out an email expressing that something changed !!!

Try something like this:

```
FIRST_READ=1
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A -e"SHOW MASTER STATUS" > /tmp/ms.txt
    currfile=`cat /tmp/ms.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
    currsize=`cat /tmp/ms.txt | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [ ${FIRST_READ} -eq 0 ]
    then
        SOMETHING_CHANGED=2
        if [ "${prevfile}" == "${currfile}" ] ; then (( SOMETHING_CHANGED-- )) ; fi
        if [ "${prevsize}" == "${currsize}" ] ; then (( SOMETHING_CHANGED-- )) ; fi
        if [ ${SOMETHING_CHANGED} -gt 0 ]
        then
            echo "Something Changed" | mail -s "Something Changed Subject" abc@xyz.com
        fi
    fi
    FIRST_READ=0
    prevfile=${currfile}
    prevsize=${currsize}
    sleep 10
done
```

**Option 2 : You Could Monitor information_schema.tables**

You could loop through every table and check its UPDATE_TIME column in information_schema.tables

First collect all table names prepended with database. Then, loop through all the table names and check that entry in information_schema.tables.

Try the following (Any table that changed in the last 10 minutes):

```
mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') AND engine IS NOT NULL" > /tmp/TableNamesToPoll.txt

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    for DBTB in `cat /tmp/TableNamesToPoll.txt`
    do
        DB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
        TB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`
        NEWUPDATE=`mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT IFNULL(update_time,NOW() - INTERVAL 100 YEAR) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) UpdatedRecently FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${DB}' AND table_name='${TB}'"`
        if [ ${NEWUPDATE} -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo "Something Changed in ${DBTB}" | mail -s "Something Changed Subject" abc@xyz.com
        fi
    done
    sleep 5
done
```

These are just skeleton scripts to detect changes. For option 1, you can do mysqlbinlog against the current binary log and see the SQL that was executed in whatever timeframe you need. For option 2, you can change the SQL to retrieve the datetime stamp of the last update for a given table.

UPDATE 2011-06-29 06:30 EDT

**Option 3 : You Could Monitor the general log**

Interestingly, you could activate the general log. What's even more intriguing is that you can activate it a MySQL Table. The template to the general log as a table already exists in /var/lib/mysql/mysql as general_log.CSV. Here are the steps:

Step 01) Add these to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-output=TABLE
log
```

Step 02) service mysql restart (general_log is a CSV table after restart)

Step 03) Run these commands to convert the general_Log from CSV to MyISAM

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ENGINE = MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ADD INDEX (event_time);
```

Step 04) Move the general_log file to a huge disk volume that can accommodate a fast growing log table

Example: If you have the following disk layout

```
[root@iml-db10 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg1-root  117G  3.2G  108G   3% /
/dev/mapper/vg2-data01
                      1.7T  688G  877G  44% /data
/dev/sdc1             3.6T   36G  3.4T   2% /backup
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   77M  19% /boot
tmpfs                  95G     0   95G   0% /dev/shm
none                   16G   51M   16G   1% /var/tmpfs
```

Perform these steps to move the general log table:

```
mkdir /backup/general_log
mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MY* /backup/general_log/.
chown -R mysql:mysql /backup/general_log
ln -s /backup/general_log/general_log.MYD /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYD
ln -s /backup/general_log/general_log.MYI /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYI
```

When do make sure the symlinks exist

```
[root@db1]# ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general*
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 8776 Jun 25 15:53 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.frm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    35 Jun 25 18:33 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYD -> /backup/general_log/general_log.MYD
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    35 Jun 25 18:32 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYI -> /backup/general_log/general_log.MYI
```

Step 05) Run this SQL command

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

That's it. You should have the general_log as a MyISAM table

```
mysql> show create table mysql.general_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: general_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `event_time` (`event_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log' DATA DIRECTORY='/backup/general_log/' INDEX DIRECTORY='/backup/general_log/'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

All you need to do is poll the general_log table every 15 minutes via crontab running this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) UpdateCount FROM mysql.general_log
WHERE LOCATE('UPDATE',argument) > 0
AND event_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);

SELECT COUNT(1) DeleteCount FROM mysql.general_log
WHERE LOCATE('DELETE',argument) > 0
AND event_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

WARNING : Entries will pile up quickly. Delete all events keeping the last 3 days. Run this in a crontab every night a midnight

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.general_log;
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
DELETE FROM mysql.general_log WHERE event_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = @old_log_state;
```

Give this a Try !!!

Comment: On a side note: I'd go for a `mysql --defaults-file=...` instead of a `mysql -u... -p...` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have vps or dedicated server, You can code your own module using C programming.

para.h

```
/* 
 * File:   para.h
 * Author: rahul
 *
 * Created on 10 February, 2016, 11:24 AM
 */

#ifndef PARA_H
#define  PARA_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


#define From "<dgdfg@dgfdgd.com>"
#define To "<dfgdfg.dfg@gmail.com>" 
#define From_header "Rahul<fdgdfg@dfgdfg.com>"   
#define TO_header "Mini<dfgdffefg@gmail.com>"   
#define UID "smtp server account ID"
#define PWD "smtp server account PWD"
#define domain "dfgdfgdfg.com"


#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  
/* PARA_H */
```

main.c

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: rahul
 *
 * Created on 10 February, 2016, 10:29 AM
 */
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "time.h"
#include "para.h"

/*
 * 
 */

my_bool SendEmail_init(UDF_INIT *initid,UDF_ARGS *arg,char *message);
void SendEmail_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)));
char* SendEmail(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *arg,char *result,unsigned long *length, char *is_null,char* error);

/*
 * base64
 */
int Base64encode_len(int len);
int Base64encode(char * coded_dst, const char *plain_src,int len_plain_src);

int Base64decode_len(const char * coded_src);
int Base64decode(char * plain_dst, const char *coded_src);

/* aaaack but it's fast and const should make it shared text page. */
static const unsigned char pr2six[256] =
{
    /* ASCII table */
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64
};

int Base64decode_len(const char *bufcoded)
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);

    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    return nbytesdecoded + 1;
}

int Base64decode(char *bufplain, const char *bufcoded)
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register unsigned char *bufout;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);
    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    bufout = (unsigned char *) bufplain;
    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (nprbytes > 4) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    bufin += 4;
    nprbytes -= 4;
    }

    /* Note: (nprbytes == 1) would be an error, so just ingore that case */
    if (nprbytes > 1) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    }
    if (nprbytes > 2) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    }
    if (nprbytes > 3) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    }

    *(bufout++) = '\0';
    nbytesdecoded -= (4 - nprbytes) & 3;
    return nbytesdecoded;
}

static const char basis_64[] =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

int Base64encode_len(int len)
{
    return ((len + 2) / 3 * 4) + 1;
}

int Base64encode(char *encoded, const char *string, int len)
{
    int i;
    char *p;

    p = encoded;
    for (i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 3) {
    *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
    *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) |
                    ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
    *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2) |
                    ((int) (string[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
    *p++ = basis_64[string[i + 2] & 0x3F];
    }
    if (i < len) {
    *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
    if (i == (len - 1)) {
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4)];
        *p++ = '=';
    }
    else {
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) |
                        ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2)];
    }
    *p++ = '=';
    }

    *p++ = '\0';
    return p - encoded;
}

/*
 end of base64
 */

const char* GetIPAddress(const char* target_domain) {
    const char* target_ip;
    struct in_addr *host_address;
    struct hostent *raw_list = gethostbyname(target_domain);
    int i = 0;
    for (i; raw_list->h_addr_list[i] != 0; i++) {
        host_address = raw_list->h_addr_list[i];
        target_ip = inet_ntoa(*host_address);
    }
    return target_ip;
}

char * MailHeader(const char* from, const char* to, const char* subject, const char* mime_type, const char* charset) {

    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    char *app_brand = "Codevlog Test APP";
    char* mail_header = NULL;
    char date_buff[26];
    char Branding[6 + strlen(date_buff) + 2 + 10 + strlen(app_brand) + 1 + 1];
    char Sender[6 + strlen(from) + 1 + 1];
    char Recip[4 + strlen(to) + 1 + 1];
    char Subject[8 + 1 + strlen(subject) + 1 + 1];
    char mime_data[13 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 13 + 1 + strlen(mime_type) + 1 + 1 + 8 + strlen(charset) + 1 + 1 + 2];

    strftime(date_buff, (33), "%a , %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

    sprintf(Branding, "DATE: %s\r\nX-Mailer: %s\r\n", date_buff, app_brand);
    sprintf(Sender, "FROM: %s\r\n", from);
    sprintf(Recip, "To: %s\r\n", to);
    sprintf(Subject, "Subject: %s\r\n", subject);
    sprintf(mime_data, "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: %s; charset=%s\r\n\r\n", mime_type, charset);

    int mail_header_length = strlen(Branding) + strlen(Sender) + strlen(Recip) + strlen(Subject) + strlen(mime_data) + 10;

    mail_header = (char*) malloc(mail_header_length);

    memcpy(&mail_header[0], &Branding, strlen(Branding));
    memcpy(&mail_header[0 + strlen(Branding)], &Sender, strlen(Sender));
    memcpy(&mail_header[0 + strlen(Branding) + strlen(Sender)], &Recip, strlen(Recip));
    memcpy(&mail_header[0 + strlen(Branding) + strlen(Sender) + strlen(Recip)], &Subject, strlen(Subject));
    memcpy(&mail_header[0 + strlen(Branding) + strlen(Sender) + strlen(Recip) + strlen(Subject)], &mime_data, strlen(mime_data));
    return mail_header;
}

my_bool SendEmail_init(UDF_INIT *initid,UDF_ARGS *arg,char *message){
     if (!(arg->arg_count == 2)) {
        strcpy(message, "Expected two arguments");
        return 1;
    }

    arg->arg_type[0] = STRING_RESULT;// smtp server address
    arg->arg_type[1] = STRING_RESULT;// email body
    initid->ptr = (char*) malloc(2050 * sizeof (char));
    memset(initid->ptr, '\0', sizeof (initid->ptr));
    return 0;
}

void SendEmail_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused))){
    if (initid->ptr) {
        free(initid->ptr);
    }
}

char* SendEmail(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *arg,char *result,unsigned long *length, char *is_null,char* error){
   char *header = MailHeader(From_header, TO_header, "Hello Its a test Mail from Codevlog", "text/plain", "US-ASCII");
    int connected_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof (addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(25);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, GetIPAddress(arg->args[0]), &addr.sin_addr) == 1) {
        connect(connected_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof (addr));
    }
    if (connected_fd != -1) {
        int recvd = 0;
        const char recv_buff[4768];
        int sdsd;
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char buff[1000];
        strcpy(buff, "EHLO "); //"EHLO sdfsdfsdf.com\r\n"
        strcat(buff, domain);
        strcat(buff, "\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char _cmd2[1000];
        strcpy(_cmd2, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
        int dfdf = send(connected_fd, _cmd2, strlen(_cmd2), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char _cmd3[1000];
        Base64encode(&_cmd3, UID, strlen(UID));
        strcat(_cmd3, "\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd3, strlen(_cmd3), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char _cmd4[1000];
        Base64encode(&_cmd4, PWD, strlen(PWD));
        strcat(_cmd4, "\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd4, strlen(_cmd4), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char _cmd5[1000];
        strcpy(_cmd5, "MAIL FROM: ");
        strcat(_cmd5, From);
        strcat(_cmd5, "\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd5, strlen(_cmd5), 0);
        char skip[1000];
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, skip, sizeof (skip), 0);

        char _cmd6[1000];
        strcpy(_cmd6, "RCPT TO: ");
        strcat(_cmd6, To); //
        strcat(_cmd6, "\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd6, strlen(_cmd6), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char _cmd7[1000];
        strcpy(_cmd7, "DATA\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd7, strlen(_cmd7), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        send(connected_fd, header, strlen(header), 0);
        send(connected_fd, arg->args[1], strlen(arg->args[1]), 0);
        char _cmd9[1000];
        strcpy(_cmd9, "\r\n.\r\n.");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd9, sizeof (_cmd9), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);
        recvd += sdsd;

        char _cmd10[1000];
        strcpy(_cmd10, "QUIT\r\n");
        send(connected_fd, _cmd10, sizeof (_cmd10), 0);
        sdsd = recv(connected_fd, recv_buff + recvd, sizeof (recv_buff) - recvd, 0);

        memcpy(initid->ptr, recv_buff, strlen(recv_buff));
        *length = recvd;
    }
    free(header);
    close(connected_fd);
    return initid->ptr;
}
```

To configure your project go through this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm2pKTW5z98 (Send Email from MySQL 5.7 on Linux)