# Where are partitions defined in mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a large table that I want to spread across multiple disks/LUNs.  It will contain blobs and I want to have it separated out from the other data.

How do I go from new disks (lets call them sdb1 and sdc1, the OS, etc. is on sdba1) attached to a (virtual) Linux database server to putting the parts of the database, really one table spread across a couple dedicated devices.

Have looked at the Partition information but its unclear how I change the location of the partitions so everything just doesn't end up in the same data directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [**CREATE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) syntax where you can declare the data folder and index folder under the `partition_definition` of a `partition_option`:

```
partition_options:
    PARTITION BY
        { [LINEAR] HASH(expr)
        | [LINEAR] KEY(column_list)
        | RANGE{(expr) | COLUMNS(column_list)}
        | LIST{(expr) | COLUMNS(column_list)} }
    [PARTITIONS num]
    [SUBPARTITION BY
        { [LINEAR] HASH(expr)
        | [LINEAR] KEY(column_list) }
      [SUBPARTITIONS num]
    ]
    [(partition_definition [, partition_definition] ...)]

partition_definition:
    PARTITION partition_name
        [VALUES 
            {LESS THAN {(expr | value_list) | MAXVALUE} 
            | 
            IN (value_list)}]
        [[STORAGE] ENGINE [=] engine_name]
        [COMMENT [=] 'comment_text' ]
        [DATA DIRECTORY [=] 'data_dir'] <<<<<---------
        [INDEX DIRECTORY [=] 'index_dir'] <<<<<---------
        [MAX_ROWS [=] max_number_of_rows]
        [MIN_ROWS [=] min_number_of_rows]
        [TABLESPACE [=] tablespace_name]
        [NODEGROUP [=] node_group_id]
        [(subpartition_definition [, subpartition_definition] ...)]
```

## CAVEATS

- I know it works for MyISAM because I wrote about it in September 2011 : [Dynamically changeable database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/dynamically-changeable-database/5965#5965). For an already existing MyISAM table, it can done from the OS by moving the `.MYD` and `.MYI` to another disk and setting up two symlinks. I wrote about that in May 2012 : [Can I have one table be an "alias", or "symlink", to another?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18425/can-i-have-one-table-be-an-alias-or-symlink-to-another/18426#18426). When done correctly, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will display `DATA DIRECTORY` and `INDEX DIRECTORY` and their respective folders.
- I personally implemented this in production for a client when I did the following

  - Converted mysql.general_log from CSV to MyISAM
  - Moved `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYD` to a large 3TB disk
  - Moved `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYI` to a large 3TB disk
  - Setup `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYD` as a symlink to the real `.MYD`
  - Setup `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.MYI` as a symlink to the real `.MYI`
  - enabled the general log
  - Watched the client's general log growth to 1.1TB
  - I wrote up how to set this up back in June 2011 : [Mail alert from MySQL when databases are edited](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/mail-alert-from-mysql-when-databases-are-edited/3162#3162) (under `Option 3 : You Could Monitor the general log`)
- Using hard links, it can be done to MyISAM tables in Windows, although the effort to do so may not be worth it. I wrote about that back in January 2012 : [Can I specify a different disk for a specific MySQL table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10108/can-i-specify-a-different-disk-for-a-specific-mysql-table/10109#10109)
- I do not believe `[DATA DIRECTORY [=] 'data_dir']` and `[INDEX DIRECTORY [=] 'index_dir']` were implemented for InnoDB. Even if the it were implemented for InnoDB, I would adamently advised against it and I wrote about why you should not back in August 2011 : [MySQL InnoDB data file directly on a disk slice (fixed-size)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/mysql-innodb-data-file-directly-on-a-disk-slice-fixed-size/4425#4425)

## Your Original Question

**MySQL 5.5 Only** : With regard to your question in the heading, `Where are partitions defined in mysql`, you can run this query to locate all tables that have partitions:

```
select count(1) partition_count,table_schema,table_name
from information_schema.partitions
group by table_schema,table_name
having count(1) > 1;
```

Here is a sample:

```
mysql> select count(1) partition_count,table_schema,table_name
    -> from information_schema.partitions
    -> group by table_schema,table_name
    -> having count(1) > 1;
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| partition_count | table_schema | table_name              |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|              31 | clickit      | t_keyword_conversion_ga |
|               2 | part         | myoldpart               |
|               3 | test         | messages                |
|             256 | test         | ngram_key               |
|               2 | test         | rc1                     |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (1.60 sec)

mysql>
```

You can get the complete definition by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE db.tbl\G` from any table from the result of that query.